# Набор контакта в телефонной книге через Viber

Tags: java, android

Есть задача: позвонить контакту через `Viber` для этого есть следующий код:

```
public static void callViber(String dialNumber, Context context) {
    Uri uri = getUriFromPhoneNumber(dialNumber,context);
    if (uri != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        intent.setClassName("com.viber.voip", "com.viber.voip.SystemDialogActivityPublic");
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Number is not in Viber Contacts List", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private static Uri getUriFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
    Uri uri = null;
    String contactId = getContactIdByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, context);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contactId)) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID},
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA2 + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{"Viber", contactId}, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    uri = Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
                    break;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return uri;
}

private static String getContactIdByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String contactId = null;
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};

    Cursor cursor =
            contentResolver.query(
                    uri,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactId;
}
```

Я подаю номер телефона в метод, далее определяеться его айдишник в телефонной книге и с этим айдишником дальше мы получаем `URI` который потом мы закладываем в `Intent` для вызова `Viber`. Получаеться что нужно что  бы данный контакт был сохранен в телефонной книге девайса.

Вопрос: что делать если в моем приложении контакты хранятся не в БД телефона, а скажем в  `Realm` как мне в таком случай вызвать `Viber` ?

Comment: найти контакт из БД телефона, больше никак

Comment: @andreich   т.е. никаким другим способом сформировать  URI я не могу? и соответственно сделать вызов   Viber  по-другому тоже нельзя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суля по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171083/3212712) можно так:

```
String sphone = "12345678";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(sphone)); 
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.setClassName("com.viber.voip", "com.viber.voip.WelcomeActivity");
intent.setData(uri); 
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: да, это работает, но проблема в том, что в варианте который я описал в вопросе при вызове активити сразу начинаеться звонок, в этом же случае если такой контакт есть в  Viber   то меня просто кидает на экран  самого контакта, а если такого контакта нету нигде ни в Viber ни в телефоне то кидает просто  в Viber список контактов

Comment: @KirillStoianov, там же пишут "According to Viber's manifest, there is activity "com.viber.voip.phone.PhoneActivity" that is responsible for action "com.viber.voip.action.CALL". In new version of Viber (4.2.1.1) this activity is marked by android:exported="false". As result, it's not possible anymore to start this activity from external applications..." что раньше было можно, а теперь - низзя. Только так. Насколько я понял

Comment: т.е. если контакта нету в телефонной книге девайса - то сразу сделать вызов я не могу, только открыть сам Viber, правильно?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, похоже что так. Но это я только чуть гугл покопал - сам ни разу не пробовал)

Comment: а не подскажите где можно почитать подробней об этом?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, я не знаю. Тут, на английской версии разве что..

Comment: "тут" - это на SO  или там должна была быть ссылка?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, не, ссылки у меня нема... Попробуйте чрез поиск на англ версии поискать. Хотя, как мне кажется, если бы всё было просто, то я бы сразу нашёл) Но, может, вам больше повезёт)

Comment: спасибо, буду гуглить!